# How to expand a Toggle upwards in react bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, toggle, navbar, react-bootstrap

I'm experimentating react bootstrap.

With the component `Navbar.Collapse`, to expand a `NavDropdown` upwards, i found this property `drop="up"`

```
<Navbar>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
  <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
      <Nav>
         <NavDropdown drop="up"
              title="Changer la police" 
              id="basic-nav-nav"
               onSelect={changeFont} >                 
                  <NavDropdown.Item
                    className={font.name}
                    eventKey={font.name}>
                    {font.name}
                  </NavDropdown.Item>                      
        </NavDropdown>
     </Nav>
   </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

But i didn't find the equivalent for `Navbar.Toggle`, to as well expand upwards instead of downwards.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,

I added this code to the css :

```
.CustomFooter .navbar-collapse {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
}
/* 1000px because this is the point where toggle disappears */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .CustomFooter .navbar-collapse {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

So it's get the impression of collapsing upwards